# Why does pytesseract fail to recognize digits in this simple image?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use pytesseract to recognize two numbers from an image:

[image]

- I have tried `--psm 6` up to `10`
- I have tried `-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'`

None of the above returns `49` number. Closest I got is returned `4` without `9`

Do you have any tips about how to make tesseract recognize it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `--psm 13 --oem 3` (`oem` = 1 or 2 should do also)

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import requests
import io

response = requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAAXR.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content)), lang='eng',
                    config='--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')

print(text)
```

yields `49` as you expect on my machine.

I get the same result by downloading the image locally and firing

```
tesseract oAAXR.png output --oem 3 --psm 13 -l eng
```

For reference my `tesseract --version` gives 
`tesseract 4.0.0 leptonica-1.77.0  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 2.0.1) : libpng 1.6.36 : libtiff 4.0.10 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 1.0.1 Found AVX2 Found AVX Found SSE`.

Comment: Where is --psm 13 documented? I only see 1-10 here: [TESSERACT(1) Manual Page](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc).

Comment: Aw, looks like their documentation may be inconsistent or refers to different versions there, check https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage for psm > 10.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your code gives me "ay" string instead of 49. 

tesseract versions:
 tesseract 4.0.0
  leptonica-1.77.0
   libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 9c : libpng 1.6.36 : libtiff 4.0.10 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 1.0.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found SSE

I'm also using MacOS (Mojave). Maybe that has something to do with it

Comment: I have edited the answer with my config, not sure what could be going wrong :(

Comment: Yeah I can see that only difference is: your libjpeg is 8d and my libjpeg 9c. Everything else is same.

Comment: This is the fastest ODR I've found after a lot of research. Most number recognition solutions are outdated, but for 2021 this works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried different `--oem` ? I would also try to use a `--psm` higher than 10.

Answer (score 1):

For me the following command just returns `4`:

```
tesseract oAAXR.png out --dpi 300 --psm 11 --oem 1 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789
```

Using:

```
tesseract 4.1.1-rc2-17-g6343
 leptonica-1.76.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.2) : libpng 1.6.36 : libtiff 4.0.10 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE
 Found libarchive 3.3.3 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.4 bz2lib/1.0.6 liblz4/1.8.3 libzstd/1.3.8
```