# Why will tesseract not detect this letter?

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I am trying to detect this letter but it doesn't seem to recognize it.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract as tess
img = cv2.imread("letter.jpg")
imggray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(tess.image_to_string(imggray))
```

this is the image in question:

[image: A letter]

Comment: Can you please add the error message?

Comment: What is it recognizing it as?

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessing of the image (e.g. inverting it) should help, and also you could take advantage of pytesseract `image_to_string` config options.

For instance, something along these lines:

```py
import pytesseract 
import cv2 as cv
import requests
import numpy as np
import io

# I read this directly from imgur
response = requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGFAu.jpg') 
nparr = np.frombuffer(response.content, np.uint8)
img = cv.imdecode(nparr, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
# simple inversion as preprocessing
neg_img = cv.bitwise_not(img)
# invoke tesseract with options
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(neg_img, config='--psm 7')

print(text)
```

should parse the letter correctly.

Have a look at related questions for some additional info about preprocessing and tesseract options:
[Why does pytesseract fail to recognise digits from image with darker background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55994807/pytesseract-fail-to-recognise-digits-from-image)
[Why does pytesseract fail to recognize digits in this simple image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53998699/why-does-pytesseract-fail-to-recognize-digits-in-this-simple-image)
[Why does tesseract fail to read text off this simple image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261255/why-does-tesseract-fail-to-read-text-off-this-simple-image)

Answer (score 1):

@Davide Fiocco 's answer is definitely correct.

I just want to show another way of doing it with `adaptive-thresholding`

When you apply `adaptive-thesholding` result will be:

[image]

Now when you read it:

```py
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 7")
print(txt)
```

Result:

```sh
B
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("LGFAu.jpg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 252, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 7")
print(txt)
```